# How to automate testing of different launch options in iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, integration-testing, kiwi, kif-framework

I was wondering if there was a way to automate testing of different configurations of `launchOptions` when the app first launches? I am familiar with XCTest, KIF and KIWI but I'm not sure if it's possible to implement that sort of tests?

Comment: Do you have a way to automate that in your integration testing? KIF is meant to be an integration testing framework but I'm not sure if it supports that use case.

Comment: I've updated question to remove references to 'unit testing'

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can always to put app to state as it was with first run. I mean in AppDelegate with

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

you can always react on launchOptions to set app state before each test or before all test - that depends on your actual test.